# Android Fragments: restore programmatically added views

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, view-hierarchy

I have two fragments: **fragmentA** and **fragmentB**

In **fragmentA**, some views have been programmatically added

If from **fragmentA** I go to **fragmentB** and then I come back to **fragmentA**, all the programmatically added views are not there anymore

Which is the way to restore the programmatically added views inside the view hierarchy?

Comment: I think the best solution is always the logic code depend on the check value. Add it view automatically when check is false.

Comment: what do you mean for check value?

Comment: Oke. Save check = true in onSaveInstanceState. Get it in onActivityCreated() when back to fragment A. and onCreate you will addView depend on you check value.... And if u want to know why "If from fragmentA I go to fragmentB and then I come back to fragmentA, all the programmatically added views are not there anymore" please post your code

Comment: when I get back to fragment A, in onActivityCreated() the programmatically added views are never there (I am testing it using layout.getChildCount)

Comment: somewhere I read you need to set an id to the programmatically added view. I am specifying it using view.setId(), but they still don't get restored

Comment: I think onSaveInstanceState is null when you come back to FragmentA, it is different from null only when the activity is destroyed

Comment: sorry for long time to answer, I think u have fragment as adapter in Viewpager.

Comment: i think the problem is very small, store check value some where(database, other class, xml,..), get it and check in oncreate. So you can do anything. Sorry if i wrong